# Default choice (in batch) not working after timeout

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have created a script to copy a file to a directory, yet prompt you if the file already exists. this current code doesn't work as intended if yes is selected, but the file already exists and then no input is given at the second prompt. Meaning in the `exist` section it doesn't default to the no option when the timeout time is over.

```
:: This is a script to move downloaded files into a folder titled with todays date
@echo ---------------------------------
@echo ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO PROCEED?
@echo ---------------------------------
@echo off 
::present user with Yes/No option
choice /C YN /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No." /T 10 /D N
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto:yes
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto:no

:yes
if exist "%date:/=_%\cE0MB.m4a" (
goto EXIST
) else (goto MOVE)
:MOVE
if exist cE0MB.m4a (
md "%date:/=_%"
move cE0MB.m4a "%date:/=_%\cE0MB.m4a"
) else (echo FILES NOT DOWNLOADED, PLEASE DOWNLOAD THEN RUN SCRIPT AGAIN)
if exist "%date:/=_%\cE0MB.m4a" echo FILE SUCCESSFULLY COPIED TO DIRECTORY
TIMEOUT /T  5 >nul
exit

:EXIST
if exist cE0MB.m4a (
choice /C YN /M "Files already exist, overwrite?" /T 5 /D N
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto:move
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto:no
) else (echo NOTHING TO COPY, CLOSING...)
TIMEOUT /T  3 >nul
exit 

:no
echo YOU HAVE SELECTED NO OR WAITED TOO LONG TO RESPOND
echo PRESS ANY KEY OR WAIT TO EXIT
TIMEOUT /T  5 >nul
exit
```

however if i modify the `exist` section to the following, it works as intended

```
:EXIST
if exist cE0MB.m4a (
choice /C NY /M "Files already exist, overwrite?" /T 5 /D N
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto:no
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto:move
) else (echo NOTHING TO COPY, CLOSING...)
TIMEOUT /T  3 >nul
exit
```

Can anybody tell me why? I don't see any obvious conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question directly. `choice` sets a value based on the position of choices, because setting values inside of a code block requires `delayedexpansion` you need to do the same when running choice inside of a code block. Currently, when you enter the code block with the previously defined `errorlevel` it will remain `1` inside of the loop. So simply do:

```
:EXIST
if exist cE0MB.m4a (
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   choice /C YN /M "Files already exist, overwrite?" /T 5 /D N
   if "!errorlevel!"=="1" goto:move
   if "!errorlevel!"=="2" goto:no
   endlocal
) else (
   echo NOTHING TO COPY, CLOSING...
)
TIMEOUT /T 3 >nul
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It confines the responses to the ```EXIST``` section and doesn't let the goto function work as it should. I select Y which should trigger the ```goto:move```, but it doesn't, it simply proceeds to ```TIMEOUT``` and closes.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't notice that the ```%``` had been changed to ```!``` this works as intended. I'll have to do some research about the delayed expansion to find out how it works. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, so you can simply from `cmd` run `set /?` and `setlocal /?` to read about `delayedexpansion`